# template in cpp

Tags: c++, templates

I hav a following piece of code in a module.

Controller is the name of the class.
allocate_route is the member function of it.

While defining the member function it is given as

```
template<UI num_ip>
void Controller<num_ip>::allocate_route()
{
}
```

UI is Unsigned Integer. `num_ip` is not defined any where. He also has not used `num_ip` anywhere inside the code. What does he tell to the compiler by this statement. Am not able to comprehend the use of templates here. Wat does this code do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code implements the function `allocate_route` defined in the template class `Controller`.

When creating template classes, you have two way to implement functions:

```
template <int a>
class A
{
   void x() { ... }
};
```

or

```
template <int a>
class A
{
   void x();
};

template <int a>
void A<a>::x()
{
}
```

Comment: @CHID: please flag the question as anwered :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he is using `num_ip` somewhere outside this method, but still inside `Controller` class (maybe another method).

If you define method inside a template you have to add `template<...>`, even if method doesn't use template parameters. That's why it could be better to do something like this in this case:

```
class Controller_base
{
  void allocate_route(){
  }
};

template<UI num_ip>
class Controller: public Controller_base
{
}

void Controller_base::allocate_route()
{
}
```